Can someone point the source of this verse?
The website says it is mentioned in Vishnu Dharma-
yo'nyatra kurute yatnam
dharma karye dvijottamah
vihaya sandhya pranatim
sa yati narakayutam
Can someone point the exact location of this verse thanks.
